# npm - Can I publish python code as npm package

Tags: python, npm

Is it possible to publish a project written in python, to npm registry? I would like to do this in order for the internal teams to use this code as a library as part of their development

Comment: https://blog.packagecloud.io/resources/how-to-publish-python-packages-on-npm/

Comment: thanks for providing the link. I had come across this, but I'm looking for free options. Like is npm compatible with python?